# Program received signal: “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”

Tags: c

This `fgets(myDiscPointer->songArray[0], 21, stdin);` 
causes my program to crash. I have the following in my struct.

```
typedef struct 
{
char Artist[21];
char Album[21];
int Year;
char **songArray;
}CD;
```

and I declare the following

```
CD myDisc;
CD *myDiscPointer = &myDisc;
```

Another thing that was happening is that my #define was complained about by Xcode.

> #define MAXCHARATCERS  21

This was seen as undeclared when I used it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where an how are you allocating the memory for `songArray`? You'd need something like this:

```
#define MAXARTIST 20
#define MAXALBUM 20

typedef struct 
{
    char Artist[MAXARTIST+1];
    char Album[MAXALBUM+1];
    int Year;
    int songs;
    char **songArray;
} CD;

CD *allocCD(char const * const artist, char const * const album, int year)
{
    CD *cd = malloc(sizeof(*cd));
    if(!cd)
        return 0;

    strncpy(cd->Artist, artist, MAXARTIST);
    strncpy(cd->Album, album, MAXALBUM);
    cd->Year = year;
    cd->songs = 0;
    cd->songArray = 0;

    return cd;
}

int addSongToCD(CD * const cd, char const * const song)
{
    char **newArray;
    char *newSong;

    newSong = malloc(strlen(song)+1);
    if(!newSong)
         return 0;

    strdup(newSong, song); /* strdup uses strlen so malloc(strlen(...)+1) is sufficient, no need for the strndup max length safety net */

    newArray = realloc(cd->songArray, sizeof(newArray*) * (cd->songs + 1));

    if(!newArray) {
        free(newSong); /* don't leak memory */
        return 0;
    }

    cd->songArray = newArray;
    cd->songArray[cd->songs++] = newSong;

    return cd->songs;
}

void freeCD(CD * const cd)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i < cd->songs; ++i) {
        free(cd->songArray[i]);
    }
    free(cd->songArray);
}
```

Comment: Doesnt CD *cd = malloc(sizeof(*cd)); only allocate memory large enough for a pointer?

Comment: Wit "CD *cd" is a pointer thus "sizeof(*cd)" is the size of the type yielded if that pointer is dereferenced. So: No. "CD *cd = malloc(sizeof(*cd));" allocates exactly the amount of memory needed for the type, the pointer points to.

Comment: Thanks. Why do you use the "const" in all the function declarations?

Comment: Since it allows you to use string literals. 'char *hello_there= "hello there";' has a different meaning as 'char mutable_string[]="I'm mutable";' The former puts the string "hello there" into a read only section of the program image and gives you a pointer of type "char const * const" to that - the other reserves some memory at runtime and initialized it with "I'm mutable", and the contents of that are also writable. To be able to pass both variants the type must be of a pointer to immutable values, i.e. "char const", the pointers itself are marked const, so that one doesn't overwrite them.

Comment: Oh and before you ask, why "char const" and not "const char", that's because the const storage classifier operates on the token left to it. The exception is if const is the first token in a statement, then it operates towards the right. I prefer things to be consistent and "char const * const" makes more sense and looks nicer to me than "const char * const".

Answer (score 2):

You are not allocating memory for the `songArray`, which causes the program to crash when you write into random places.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't you used `MAXCHARACTERS` after? Probably because of typo.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the #define, MAXCHARATCERS would seem to be a typo 
(the last c and t are reversed).  Is that just a typo here or is the typo causing an issue in your code as well?